# Implementation of Machine Learning model in Outlook

Tags: vba, machine-learning, outlook, outlook-addin, production

Is it possible to implement email classification model in Microsoft outlook ? I have created a classification model, but since I am not aware of functionalities in Outlook, I am not sure how I can implement the same. I read that an additional add-in can be created in MS Outlook, but not sure, how to do the same. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You already tagged your question with all the right tags. Using the same tags to search on Google, will bring hundreds of links on how to create a web based (JS) addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio) or a COM based (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2017) addin.